# "ERROR in window is not defined" webpack general error on webpack --mode=production --env.prod

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I'm trying to deploy my first angular app but during the execution of deploy, in the middle of the command:

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode=production --env.prod
```

(A.K.A. `webpack  --mode=production --config webpack.config.js --env.prod`)

I get a generic error which does not provide me more informations than the following:

> ```
> Hash: 7b126cdcbdda85d6b0f304152e501136ec85ed58
> Version: webpack 4.6.0
> Child
>     Hash: 7b126cdcbdda85d6b0f3
>     Time: 13298ms
>     Built at: 2018-04-23 12:27:51
>      1 asset
>     Entrypoint main-client = main-client.js
>
>     ERROR in window is not defined
> Child
>     Hash: 04152e501136ec85ed58
>     Time: 13281ms
>     Built at: 2018-04-23 12:27:51
>      1 asset
>     Entrypoint main-server = main-server.js
>
>     ERROR in window is not defined
> ```

Main-server and Main-client are both webpack-generated files and the only usage of "window" in my code is to execute the `window.history.back()` command but even commenting it, the error still comes up.

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

My webpack version is 4.6.0 <del>and my webpack.config.js content is the following:</del> 

|| 
 ===> **UPDATE** - unnecessary webpack.config.js content as not related to the issue itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably cause because you're referring to `window` directly somewhere in your code. THIS IS NOT BEST PRACTISE!! Sometimes, (Server side) the window object is not defined and cause this problems. Same if a third-part library uses that.

So check your code first, find where you're using window directly and wrap inside a PLATFORMID like this example:

```js
 import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
 import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
 
 constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { ... }
 
 ngOnInit() {
   if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // Client only code.
      ...
   }
   if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
     // Server only code.
     ...
   }
 }
```

Or, if you can't find it, probably a library is still using it. Check this issue on github, it will explain you better than me the problem:

https://github.com/webpack/react-starter/issues/37

Hope this will help you =)

PS: same problem when i had to implement a Server Side Rendering.. I was using `window` EVERYWHERE in code. From that moment, when i have to use it, i always find another way to do the same thing.

You could also try putting `target: "web"` inside your webpack.config.js

---

**EDIT FROM THE ONE WHO ASKED THE QUESTION**

See also this issue on github, it provides the solution for this issue:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7112

Comment: Thanks Luca. I think the problem is related to some library because I've just replaced all of my Windows occurrences with Angular's built-in location.back() feature. By the way, how can I check if a library is using "window"?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have the exactly answer for your question, but i found that in my project doing a `find in folder` on node_modules, obviously excluding @angular and selenium (or any other library that comes from angular cli dependency). This is not a perfect way, but i found some referencies to `window.document` and `window.location`

Comment: Thanks! By searching with TotalCommander, I've found that JQuery is using "window". I need to find a workaround. If it works, I will mark your answer as accepted, otherwise I will tell you in another comment. By now, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I've removed JQuery module but the issue still persists. I've found out that there are a lot of necessary modules that uses it, even angular native's one. Do you know how can I avoid this issue without deleting libraries? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your edit is close enough to answer the question. But i still recommend to wrap your window inside a PLATFORM ID case (if you reference directly to window or some library methods which do it). Could you try putting 'web' in your webpack config `target`?

Comment: I need target Node because of node_modules exclusion but I'll give a try. By now, I've quite deleted all of unnecessary "window"-using dependencies and I've removed the usage of ng-tools/webpack. I will give a try later, I hope

Comment: let me know. I faced some problems with window but your case is interesting because angular libraries should not give errors although having window using inside.

Comment: I agree, but i think it's related to another library (devextreme's one). Or I hope so. By the way, target should be "web" by default in the browser side and could be node in server side, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, should be exactly like you said.

Comment: I'm going to try now... If I use a library that uses Windows, I just have to import PLATFORM ID and to inject it or should I import the library in a conditional way?

Comment: PLATFORM ID is used in YOUR CODE, not inside library, or any npm install would delete your changes. So you could wrap inside the condition the function you call from that library

Comment: What if the library is a pure graphical one?

Comment: If it’s pure graphical and uses window... change library 