# Angular node_modules: Including JQuery properly with also preventing the "window is not defined" error

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, webpack, node-modules

I open this question strictly related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981555/error-in-window-is-not-defined-webpack-general-error-on-webpack-mode-product/49982307#49982307).

As a troubleshooting to the linked question, I need to find out how to include jquery in my angular app (i need it because of bootstrap) but making sure that it not causes "window is not defined" error mentioned on the question above.

The usage of "window" javascript function made by jquery in fact causes several problems to the server side rendering with webpack.

Does anyone knows how to include JQuery in an Angular app in the right way (defining "Window" before JQuery usage or/and excluding it from server rendering)?

Or is there any node library which could help providing a declaration of "window"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `How to include jQuery in my Angular app` = usual Angular beginner's big mistake. Don't. _Ever_. Use Angular OR jQuery, never both at the same time. They are very different tools that don't work the same way. Do everything the Angular way, or the jQuery way.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks, but what about bootstrap? It needs jquery to work...is there another way to make it working with an angular app without using jquery?

Comment: Sure, there are Bootstrap versions made with Angular : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Comment: @JeremyThille All right, thanks! I can consider your comments a proper answer because now I can avoid using JQuery, avoiding also "Windows not found" issue caused by it.

Comment: @JeremyThille accepted, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include jQuery with Angular. Ever. These are two libraries that achieve similar things in a *very* different way. jQuery manipulates the DOM, but Angular generates and re-generates it on the fly as data source changes. These two guys will just interfere with each other and interact very poorly, leading to tons of hacks and workarounds, thus producing clumsy and unmaintainable code. Not to mention that you'll have to load two libraries instead of one.

Use jQuery OR Angular, never both together.

If you're switching from jQuery to Angular and you're used to jQuery plugins - and in your case, Bootstrap more specifically - most of jQuery's plugins have an Angular equivalent. Bootstrap is no exception, you can try [ng-bootstrap here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).