# Download image and pdf in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, imagedownload

I am in need of downloading an file may be it is image or pdf. 
For this I have written below code.

```
<a href="https://localhost:44344/UploadedFiles/IMG_20190314_205925_3be1d2b3-3bac-4184-8468-995d58d5ff80.jpg">Downlod image</a>
```

and

```
<a [routerLink]="https://localhost:44344/UploadedFiles/IMG_20190314_205925_3be1d2b3-3bac-4184-8468-995d58d5ff80.jpg">Downlod image</a>
```

Both are opening image in same tab, but not direct downloading.
I did not find any support for this on google, youtube etc.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - It is not working. I want to download any type of file, be it image or pdf. not just image.  help me on this.
don't downvote my question. you can try this in angular 7, the tricks in given link not working.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - My question is not duplicate, I have clearly mention "Angular 7".

Comment: Why do you think it matters that you're using Angular, 7 or otherwise? The behaviour you're describing is the same with hand-written HTML, the same fixes can be applied to your template. And what specifically *"is not working"* - have you tried something different to what you posted?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Off course yes, I have tried but the behavior  is same, it is opening in same tab instead of downloading.

Comment: @GopalSharma jonrsharpe is right, the way you are trying to download that file is the standard HTML behaviour so the question he linked should solve your issue. If you are looking for a way to download a file via HTTP request instead, you can find a question (and an answer I wrote some months ago) about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50332447/9653205

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are using for both the tags are same, instead of downloading it will open the link.

Please use blob object to download the image, see the example in this link given below:-
https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.mikehodnick.com/angular-download-image-blob-and-bind-to-img/amp/