# Webpack Bundle: (seemingly random) reference errors: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack to bundle a series of TypeScript files - an AngularJS application. The build process works without errors or warnings and the application seems to work fine, but the Chrome console reveals a handful of (seemingly random) Reference Errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined`

The application will even run without these errors for a period of time, but as the route changes, these errors will occasionally appear. I tried making the offending libraries externals and pull them in via a standard `<script>` tag and the errors turn into `angular is not defined` and appear in a similar way. Still, the app runs fine (from a user's perspective), but the console reveals these very random feeling errors.

I am stumped and I appear to be unique? I can't find others who have run into similar issues.

Screenshots of the Chrome console errors:

[image: window is not defined]
[image: offending line]

My webpack config looks like (sorry for the funky formatting, trying to condense it as much as possible):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = [
  {
    target: 'web',
    entry: './src/app.ts',
    output: {
      filename: 'my-bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        { test: /\.png$/, use: ['url-loader?mimetype=image/png'] }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: false
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.html']
    }
  }
];
```

My `app.ts` contains (most of the content removed for simplicity):

```
import './polyfills'
import * as angular from 'angular'
import * as angularUiRouter from '@uirouter/angularjs'
import { provide, bundle } from 'ng-metadata/core'
```

And finally, my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <!-- links to stylesheets and whatnot -->
</head>
<body ng-app="my-app">
    <div><ui-view></ui-view></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

The part that's killing me is that everything appears to be working fine, it's just these random errors appearing in the console. I see the same behavior in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. When things feel "random" tend to think they're timing issues. Is my webpack bundle in the right place? When I've made angular an external dependency and include it before my webpack-generated bundle, I see the "random-like" errors of `angular is not defined`. Would appreciate any insight!

Versions:

- Webpack `4.26.1`
- Angular `1.6.9`
- ng-metadata `4.0.1`
- TypeScript `2.4.0`

Comment: Can you please show us a screenshot of where the error is coming. The terminal screenshot will be great.

Comment: Oh, yes, that makes sense. Will do!

Comment: Amy, can you click on the link of `bundle.js` and try putting a debugger and see what's the context of `this`?

Comment: ps: It was me who messaged in LinkedIn to offer a help, just a heads up. 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981555/error-in-window-is-not-defined-webpack-general-error-on-webpack-mode-product

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman and where would I try to determine the context of `this` ? Anywhere within the bundle? So my `app.ts` would be fine?

Comment: I think, perhaps, a better question might be: in what scenario does a browser not have `window` defined

Comment: @amlyhamm Have you tried using the debugger in Chrome Dev Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp. After another frustrating week of debugging, I finally found my issue. I was using the [PrismJS](https://prismjs.com/) library and didn't even include it in my example above because it seemed so harmless. PrismJS is not webpack-friendly (at least not the version I was using). On a more-detailed note here, I believe the `highlightAll` method is what's troublesome.

For those who may be running into similar issues, the debugging process may stillbe helpful to you. I noticed that each time an error appeared in the console, it corresponded with another attempt to load the same `bundle.js` file. This happened several times throughout the application ("random"). Eventually, I discovered the request was coming from something Prism related and was able to make the library an external package in my webpack config, and the issue was solved!

Not all libraries will be webpack friendly. I thought I had done my due-diligence by removing a few here and there, but I apparently did not. Hope my experience can be helpful to someone else!